# XML parsing from API with Nokogiri and Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nokogiri, xml-parsing

Hi Im trying to parse XML from a websites API with Nokogiri. Im just curious to see if Im on the right track. I have a controller wich handles the parsing and then I would like the model to initialize the necessary parameters and then display it as a simple  list in the view. I was thinking something like this in the Controller:

```
def index
doc = Nokogiri::XML(open("http://www.mysomething.com/partner/api/1_0/somerandomkeynumber4b0/channel/11number/material/list/").read) 

@news = [] 

doc.css("news").each do |n|
  header = n.css("header").text
  source_name = n.css("source_name").text  
  summary = n.css("summary").text 
  url = i.css("url").text
  created_at = i.css("created_at").text
  type_of_media = i.css("type_of_media").text

  @news << News.new(
                    :header => header,)
end
```

and then the Model:

```
class News
include ActiveModel::Validations

validates_presence_of :url, :type_of_media

attr_accessor :header, :source_name, :summary, :url, :created_at, :type_of_media  

def initialize(attributes = {})
  @header = attributes[:header]
  @source_name = attributes[:source_name]
  @summary = attributes[:summary]
  @url = attributes[:url]
  @created_at = attributes[:created_at]
  @type_of_media = attributes[:type_of_media]
end
```

Is this how you would do this?! Not sure Im thinking correct on this. Maybe you have any tips on a great way of incorporating Nokogiri with some other thing for the view like Google maps or something. Right now Im getting an error saying
`Missing template news/index with {:formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:builder, :rjs, :erb, :rhtml, :rxml], :locale=>[:en, :en]} in view paths`

Thanks in advance!

@noodle: So this:

```
  @news = doc.css('query').map do |n|
  h = {}
  %w(header source_name summary url created_at type_of_media).each do |key|
   h[key.to_sym] = n.css(key).text
  end
 News.new(h)
end
```

Is equal to:

```
@news = [] 

doc.css("news").each do |n|
  header = n.css("header").text
  source_name = n.css("source_name").text  
  summary = n.css("summary").text 
  url = i.css("url").text
  created_at = i.css("created_at").text
  type_of_media = i.css("type_of_media").text

  @news << News.new(
                :header => header,)
end
```

Did I understand you correctly?! Regarding the template I have located the the problem. It was a minor misspelling. Cheers!

Comment: Yes, those are equivalent. It's not necessarily as clear but it avoids repeating the search terms three times. You've mistaken `i` for `n` in your last example but it's close enough :)

Comment: @noodl: Yes I did indeed miss that it seems :). One last question though. On this line @news = doc.css('query') <- should it say query here or an "actual" query?? Big thanks for your great replies.

Comment: Ok. But then Im a bit confused. In my first example I did doc.css("news").each do |n| and now I should just do: @news = doc.css('news').map do |n| then? Which should be the equivalence I guess? Because you are not referring to an sql query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're really asking two questions here..

### Is my xml -> parse -> populate pipeline ok?

Yes, pretty much. As there's no conditional logic in your .each block it would be cleaner to do it like this:

```
@news = doc.css('query').map do |n|
  #...
  News.new(:blah => blah, ...)
end
```

.. but that's a minor point.

**EDIT**

You could save some typing by initializing a hash from the parsed xml and then passing that to `Model.new`, like:

```
@news = doc.css('query').map do |n|
  h = {}
  h[:header] = n.css('header').text
  # ...
  News.new(h)
end
```

**EDIT 2**

Or even shorter..

```
@news = doc.css('query').map do |n|
  h = {}
  %w(header source_name summary url created_at type_of_media).each do |key|
    h[key.to_sym] = n.css(key).text
  end
  News.new(h)
end
```

In fact `#inject` could make that shorter still but I think that'd be a little obfuscated.

### Why can't rails find my view template?

Dunno, is there one? You've not given enough details to answer that part.

Comment: Thanks for your useful feedback. Regarding the error Im doing this:rooting :to =>

Comment: @Tim: It looks like you got cut off there. Try updating you question instead.

Comment: Any one got any suggestions to way I cant seem to display the xml response in my browser??! I can print the xml object to_s and get output in the console put not display it in my view. Confused! Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry @Tim I just saw your comment when you accepted my answer. Have you sorted out the display issue now?

Comment: Yes thank you for all your help. I managed to find the solution. Thanks!